# Как включить htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

В файле `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` в `<Directory /var/www/>`

изменяю `AllowOverride` на `All`

И при после перезагрузки апача вместо сайта уже `500 Internal Server Error`.

Возможно я чтото не так делаю. Подскажите пожалуйста. `find / -name httpd.conf` никаких файлов не находит, или httpd.conf это не файл конфигурации апач?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во-первых AllowOverride там в двух местах, во-вторых

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

в-третьих: где гарантии, что в самом .htaccess все правильно?